# Print database record to a different view

Tags: php, mysql

I have designed a small PHP program to store data send (Accounts & Minutes) by our branch offices. 
Following is the database structure of the main table (`reports`). (Which stores all the records of incoming reports)

```
|Column|Type|Null|Default

|//**rid**//|int(11)|No| <-- Primary Key (Report ID)
|bid|int(2)|No| <-- Branch ID (data from `branches` table)
|mid|int(2)|No| <-- Month ID (data from `mns` table)
|yid|int(4)|No| <-- Year ID (year)
|minutes|int(1)|No| 
|accounts|int(1)|No|
|added|timestamp|No|CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

After storing data it will look like this (It will contains 100+ records);

```
| rid | bid | mid| | yid | minutes | accounts | added
| 1   |  1  |  1   | 2015 | 1      |  1        | current_time_stamp
| 2   |  2  |  2   | 2015 | 1      |  0        | current_time_stamp
| 3   |  2  |  3   | 2015 | 1      |  1        | current_time_stamp
```

Now I want to print those records into following format.
Simply I want to generate a yearly report of all branches.
System user have to select a year. (In here, i selected 2015 as the report year)

```
| branch(bid) | january            | february           | march             | blah blah blah
              | accounts | minutes | accounts | minutes |accounts | minutes |
    1         |    1     |    1    |                    |   1      |  1
    2         |                                         |   1      |  1
```

I wrote a SQL Query

```
SELECT reports.*, branches.bname, mns.mname FROM ((reports INNER JOIN branches ON reports.bid = branches.bid) INNER JOIN mns ON reports.mid = mns.mid) WHERE  yid='$year' ORDER BY mns.mid
```

Please help me to print the data into the above mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your array as follows

```
Array
(
[2015] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [minutes] => 1
                        [accounts] => 1
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [minutes] => 1
                        [accounts] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [minutes] => 1
                        [accounts] => 1
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

For this just use simple `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT r.*, b.bname, m.mname 
FROM reports r INNER JOIN branches b ON r.bid = b.bid
INNER JOIN mns m ON r.mid = m.mid
WHERE  yid='$year';
```

I don't know the array structure you get from above query...

I'm giving you my code with an array structure...

Implement it in your result array you get form query otherwise give that array to me...

My solve code is as follows.

```
    $array = array(
        array('rid'=>1,'bid'=>1,'mid'=>1,'yid'=>2015,'minutes'=>1,'accounts'=>1),
        array('rid'=>2,'bid'=>2,'mid'=>2,'yid'=>2015,'minutes'=>1,'accounts'=>0),
        array('rid'=>3,'bid'=>2,'mid'=>3,'yid'=>2015,'minutes'=>1,'accounts'=>1)
    );
    $new = array();
    foreach($array as $r){
        $new[$r['yid']][$r['bid']][$r['mid']] = array('minutes'=>$r['minutes'],'accounts' => $r['accounts']);
    }

    echo '
    <table width="100%" border="1px" align="center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Branch</th>
                <th colspan="2">Jan</th>
                <th colspan="2">Feb</th>
                <th colspan="2">Mar</th>
                <th colspan="2">Apr</th>
                <th colspan="2">May</th>
                <th colspan="2">Jun</th>
                <th colspan="2">Jul</th>
                <th colspan="2">Aug</th>
                <th colspan="2">Sep</th>
                <th colspan="2">Oct</th>
                <th colspan="2">Nov</th>
                <th colspan="2">Dec</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>';for($i=0;$i<12;$i++)echo '
                <th>Min</th>
                <th>Acc</th>';echo '
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';foreach($new[2015] as $k => $r){
            echo '<tr align="center"><td>'.$k.'</td>';for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){
                if(isset($r[$i])) echo '<td>'.$r[$i]['minutes'].'</td><td>'.$r[$i]['accounts'].'</td>';
                else  echo '<td></td><td></td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }echo '
        </tbody>
    </table>
    ';
    echo '<pre>';print_r($new);
```